# Unable to select first element during mount selection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I am using the following Element in my React Component.

Having issues when I try to test it. I am trying to find this Element

via following test code.

```
const mountRender = props => mount(<Labels {...props} />);
expect(mountRender().find('Element').first().props()).toMatchSnapshot()
```

But the find('Element') doesn't find the first Element (the header section).

It instead skips it and finds the Element.

Could I get some help on how to select the first Element (header section) pls.

This is my component Labels which I am testing.

The component Label is used inside the Labels component.

```
export const Label = ({ description }) => (
    <div>
      <Element
        // The Element at header section is skipped
        // and this Element is found instead
        Component="h3"
      >
        {description}
      </Element>
    </div>
  );
  
  const Labels = ({ description, header}) => (
    <div>
      {/* header is definitely passed in so this is true, this section renders in snapshot */}
      {header && (
        // expecting this to be found
        // but this is not the chosen Element
        <Element
          Component="h4"
        >
          {header}
        </Element>
      )}
      <Label
        description={description}
      />
    </div>
  );
  
  export default Labels;
```

This is the Element coming from an external import written in Typescript

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SupportedHtmlTags } from "./types";
interface Props {
    Component?: keyof React.ReactHTML | React.ReactType;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    className?: string;
}
declare function Element<Tag extends keyof SupportedHtmlTags>(props: {
    Component: Tag;
} & SupportedHtmlTags[Tag] & Props): JSX.Element;
declare namespace Element {
    var defaultProps: {
        Component: string;
        theme: {};
    };
}
export default Element;
```